# finding string variable in each row and generating new variable in R

Tags: r

For each row of my dataset, i have multiple string variables.

e.g.

```
  var1     var1      var3      var4
1 mother   daughter  house     tea 
2 mother   father    daughter  NA
3 house    tea       pencil    paper
```

I want to create a new variable (new) if in the row one of the following words exist:

mother, father, daughter so:

```
  var1     var1      var3      var4     new
1 mother   daughter  house     tea      1
2 mother   father    daughter  NA       1
3 house    tea       pencil    paper    0
```

Is there a way to do it? I do not even know where to begin with, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Here is one

```
our_strings <- c("mother", "daughter", "father")
df$new <- as.integer(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% our_strings)))
df

#   V1   var1     var2     var3  var4 new
# 1  1 mother daughter    house   tea   1
# 2  2 mother   father daughter  <NA>   1
# 3  3  house      tea   pencil paper   0
```

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1   = 1:3, 
  var1 = c("mother", "mother", "house"), 
  var2 = c("daughter", "father", "tea"), 
  var3 = c("house", "daughter","pencil"), 
  var4 = c("tea", NA, "paper")
)
```

Comment: Because I didn't think that I voted accidentally for you

Comment: Sorry I don't get it? You removed a semi-colon, correct?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df$new <- +(rowSums(df == "mother" | df == "daughter" | df == "father", na.rm = TRUE) > 0)

df
#    var1     var2     var3  var4 new
#1 mother daughter    house   tea   1
#2 mother   father daughter  <NA>   1
#3  house      tea   pencil paper   0
```

OR `lapply`

```
df$new <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `%in%`, c("mother", "daughter", "father"))))
```

---

We can also use `pmap_int` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(new = pmap_int(., ~+(any(c(...) %in% c("mother", "daughter", "father")))))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c("mother", "mother", "house"), var2 = 
c("daughter", "father", "tea"), var3 = c("house", "daughter", "pencil"), 
var4 = c("tea", NA, "paper")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```